# Как правильно создать REST API?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться, есть задача по созданию REST API, основной функцией является заполнение БД новостями с указанного сайта и в этом суть вопроса, как реализовать такую логику? (Клиент передаёт адрес сайта и БД начинает пополняться новостям с этого сайта)
Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто-то реализовывал нечто похожее

Comment: Речь скорее о парсере идёт. Получаем HTML страницы → Выбираем нужные заголовки кода → ... → Заносим в БД. Если, конечно, у сайта нет созданного API

Comment: Сейчас вопрос слишком общий. Разбейте его на более мелкие задачи. И задавайте конкретные вопросы по тому, что не получается.